# Why do I need SSL for my website?

Tags: security, ssl

What does SSL do and what are the bad things that can happen if I omit SSL for my website?

Comment: Why do you think you need it? Maybe you don't. Many sites don't need it. What is your site about?

Comment: No bad things, it's just so your website will support HTTPS (secured HTTP using RSA) and thus will be trusted by users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL prevents man-in-the-middle attackers from seeing or modifying data as it's sent through the internet.

Any page which contains or asks for sensitive information, or any page which involves code that executes with elevated privileges (eg, browser addins or software downloads) should use SSL for all requests.

In theory, a signed SSL certificate also indicates that the signatory has verified the identity of the site, but that doesn't mean much.

Comment: and the only reason it won't mean much is in case you have "self signed cert". but, if you got certified by a known entity (godaddy, amazon etc) it's perfectly fine.

Comment: @alfasin: Unfortunately, that is not very true.  Also, if it's self-signed, it's completely useless, since an MITM can substitute his own self-signed cert.

Comment: I'm puzzled... you say that it's not completely true and on the second part of your sentence you agree with me...

Comment: @alfasin: It is not very true that CA's perform sufficient verification.

Comment: oh, now I get you :) well, there are different levels of certs, and the "more serious" ones will be costly and will take time for them to issue  - and I bet they have protocols they must follow in order to approve your website. But I got to admit that I never had any involvement in such a process - so I can't tell for sure what's their protocols of authentication.

Comment: @alfasin: But an attacker can still try to get a valid cert from a cheaper company.

Comment: right, but in order to be able to install it the attacker needs admin access to the domain/server ;)

Answer (score 0):

Basically everything in HTML is sent in plain text formats, meaning if intercepted it could be ready very easily.

SSL makes all the plain text into encrypted mumojumbo that is extremely difficult to decrypt and read.